# OOP: Should I create two classes or one parent class and two subclasses if the two subclasses only differ in one attribute value?

Tags: oop

Let's suppose I have a class Car with color and price as its only attributes.
The price depends on the color of the car.

Since car objects will only differ in color and their corresponding price, should I just create two classes or is it better to create one superclass and two subclasses which will each have their own way to calculate the price?

Comment: Please, provide more context. As I see, you not really work with car, you work with kinda *product* and than you need completely different design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*depends on how you feel comfortable* **but** you should consider maybe you will have another car and it will have a different engine so my choice is to create a superclass but as i told it depends on how you feel comfortable

Answer (score 0):

Its better to create one superclass and then inherit it to the other classes as it easier
instead of making 2 classes because you don't have to repeat the code and its a bad practice to do so.

Hope it helped you :)